# Escaping special chars in CSS "content" property?

Tags: css, sass, css-content

I have a menu with country flags and use the CSS content property to add the name of the language.

I.e. like this:

```
a.flags::after {
    content: 'Español';
}
```

This is pretty straightforward, but the problem is that I'm working in a CMS (Shopify) that uses an SCSS stylesheet and every special character (i.e. ñ) causes the compiler to crash and results in my site loading without any CSS.
This even happens when the special character is in a comment.

So I tried escaping the chars as `'Espa&ntilde;ol'`and `'Espa&#241;ol'`, but to no avail as these don't get converted into the actual chars.

I don't have much experience with SCSS, but is there any way to get the character loaded in correctly apart from manipulating them with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the Unicode value like so:

```
a.flags::after {
    content:"Espa\00F1ol";
}
```

Which should return the normal Español when used in content as can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/42Lhjfof/1/

You can find these values by looking them up in the Unicode table, like on: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. Except when I try to replicate it for "Français" as 'Fran\00E7ais' the 'a' behind the 'ç' seems to mess up the whole thing and display a square instead of the ç. If I remove the 'a' it works and if I put a semicolon behind the unicode it also works, except that the semicolon is visible.

Comment: never mind, I just solved it by leaving a space between the unicode and the 'a'. Curiously, the space is not displayed.

Comment: Nice to hear you've found a solution, not sure why it did that with the C but it's also nice to hear a simple space will fix that!

In general content, doesn't accept any html characters and will just display them as you write them, other than unicode you can only put plain text in it (as far as I know).